# Show custom item field in Kits/Package

Tags: custom-fields, netsuite, erp

I have created a custom item fields in netsuite ERP and its show in list record. But it does not show in Kits Package. How  can I show a custom items fields in Kits package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively, the custom field will show up under the 'custom' tab on the item record.

You can also customize your 'entry form' so you can move the field from 'custom' to another sub tab of your choosing.

You can customize entry forms by either going to the item record and clicking 'Customize' in the top right or by navigating to Customization > Forms > Entry Forms.

Comment: Its working for me, thanks for your valuable comment :)

Answer (score -1):

Did you ticked the Kit/Packaged checkbox under the Applies To of the custom field?